# How to integrate parasoft soatest with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, soa, parasoft

Is it possible to integrate Parasoft SOA webservices test with Jenkins?

I have a soatest project created to test my webservices. I would like it to automate running soatest scripts through Jenkins in each build. Is there any possible way we can perform this task?

I hope you guys can understand the question

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the soatest project a standalone application? If so, you can invoke the soatest application as a testing step in Jenkins, for instance, using TestNG or JUnit to invoke the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use soatestcli to run tests in a Jenkins shell or batch build step, if your licence allows that.  The normal syntax is

```
soatestcli -data absolutePathToYourWorkspace -config 'user://YourTestConfigurationName' -resource YourProject/YourTestFile.tst -report .
```

You can also use the [HTML Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) plugin or [DocLinks](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin) plugin to publish your report.html to Jenkins.